# Small issue on vote link in the user profile page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, site-faq

For any new user like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1206219/user1206219), you can now see in his profile page links to the FAQ for explaining terms like answers, bounties, tag and... "votes": the latter with the [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) supposed to get to `/faq#reputation`.

[image: vote link]

That seems good, except the FAQ page has no `id=reputation` section.
It has an **`id="link-reputation"`** though, so [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#link-reputation) should be more appropriate for the "vote" reference.

Comment: Yep this is intentional (and necessary, to prevent jitters), just part of how the FAQ highlighting works...Mark already has it explained so I 'll refrain from duplicating it.

Comment: @NickCraver Excellent. I had never seen that feature before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's true there's no element with the `reputation` id, [/faq#reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) does link to the correct place.

If you deep-link to an anchor like `#reputation` in the FAQ, it highlights that section at the top so the page doesn't scroll, something you don't get with `#link-reputation`:

> [image: Reputation section]

Comment: The beginning of the page and its section "What is reputation?" seem to be quite redundant actually...

Comment: @VonC I think you might be a bit confused about how anchors work on the FAQ: if you deep-link to an anchor like `#reputation` in the FAQ, it highlights that section at the top so the page doesn't scroll. Compare [#deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) to [#link-deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#link-deletion): the former is what you should be linking to.

Comment: confused? I completely missed that fancy feature (that I *never* seen elsewhere on the web!). if you mention it a bit more clearly in your answer, I will accept it and will propose to close my question with a "by-design" status.

Comment: @VonC Revised :)